# How to use binary search in Visual Basic to search a Microsoft Access Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, binary-search

I'm creating a program in Visual Basic for a school project. The program is a very simple tool to aid in the designing of a guitar. Users must login to use the program. I have setup an Access database to store all the data on the users and their designs. At the moment the login system uses SQL queries to find the inputted username in the database:

```vb
 Private Sub cmd_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_login.Click
    Call Login_Validation()

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    'access database location
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\Guitar Builder\Guitar Builder.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    'the query:
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [Username] = '" & usn_box_login.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & psw_box_login.Text & "'", myConnection)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    ' userExists is set to true if the username user is found or false if it is not found
    Dim userExists As Boolean = False




    'if found:
    While dr.Read
        userExists = True

        FullName = dr("Full Name").ToString
        userName = dr("Username").ToString
    End While

    'checking the result
    If userExists = True Then


        Me.Hide()
        Dashboard.Show()

        Dashboard.lbl_name.Text = FullName
        Dashboard.lbl_username.Text = userName
    Else
        MsgBox("Sorry, username or password not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Login")
    End If
    usn_box_login.Clear()
    psw_box_login.Clear()
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

This works, however there must be a binary search in the program for it to pass the school's assessment. What is the easiest way to implement binary search to find the username?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Load all the users into a DataTable and search it.  Tell the instructor that passowrds should never, ever be stored as plaintext.  Ever.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. One of the advantages of using a DBMS like Access (or SQL Server, or SQLite, etc) is to *abstract away* the details of how data is retrieved and looked-up.

(Most modern database systems use special index structures for quick lookup, such as B-trees (B-trees are not Binary-search trees btw)

If the requirement is to use binary-search to find something, you need to not use something that will do it for you.

As this is for a programming exercise to demonstrate a working knowledge of data structures, I think you should remove Access completely and store data in a simple flat-file, load it all into memory when your program starts, then use your algorithms and structures to work with the data, before spitting it out to the flat-file store when your user clicks the Save button.

Note that I'm guessing using .NET's `Array.BinarySearch` is also probably cheating.

Other tips:

- Don't store passwords in plain-text. They should not be encrypted either. Instead they should be hashed (and preferably salted).
- Don't generate SQL using string concatenation. Use parameters instead. (Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: if you put the text `Baba O'Reilly` in your textboxes your program will crash.
- You should dispose of all your `IDisposable` objects correctly, ideally using a `Using` statement.
- Run FxCop (Visual Studio Code Analysis) as part of your build process to catch other issues. Choose the "All Rules" setting.

The above bullet-points might sound like nit-picking, but I believe it's important to get into good habits early. The last thing an employer needs is a new hire who added significant vulnerabilities just because they never got used to doing things correctly.

Comment: _Don't use VB.NET_ - very unmature advise :). Instead you can suggest, for example, to set `Option Strict On`. And what you mean by _VB ecosystem_?

Comment: @Fabio I've removed that comment. By the "VB ecosystem" I'm referring to sites that offer tutorials and guidance specifically for VB which, in my experience, don't follow best-practices for things like preventing SQL injection, leaking unmanaged resources, use of GDI and Office Interop in unsupported scenarios, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your advice and removed Microsoft Access completely. I am now using my own record structure within the program.